# Disabling an alert message and simply drop in jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-droppable

I have done a jQuery drag and  drop function. But there is a little mistake in there. I found a function, which has an alert message but I don't want that. I want only the the element to drop. Here is my code:

```
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery(".draggable").draggable({
  //  use a helper-clone that is append to 'body' so is not 'contained' by a pane
    helper:  function () { return jQuery(this).clone().appendTo('body').css('zIndex',5).show(); }
  ,  cursor:  'move'
  });

  jQuery('.ui-layout-center').droppable({ 
     accept:  '.draggable',
     drop:  function () { alert('The Draggable was Dropped!'); } 
  }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery(".draggable").draggable({
  //  use a helper-clone that is append to 'body' so is not 'contained' by a pane
    helper:  function () { return jQuery(this).clone().appendTo('body').css('zIndex',5).show(); }
  ,  cursor:  'move'
  });

  jQuery('.ui-layout-center').droppable({ 
     accept:  '.draggable'
  }); 
});
```

Simply leave the alert out, where is the problem?

Comment: but when i leave the alert out my element didnt drop in .ui-layout-center.

Comment: @Jackson That does not make any sense, the `drop` attribute is an event which shouldn't affect the functionality. Maybe you forgot (as I did just) the `,` in the line before. Please try again with the code above.

Comment: yes i made that. but now can you say why the drop element cant be drag in the droped place.